# Set page format in WPF FlowDocument for dot matrix printer

Tags: wpf, printing, flowdocument

I'm having an issue with a report that I'm building with FlowDocuments. I can't set the format for dot-matrix printer's sheets (they are larger than A4). 
For example, when I print the report (It has more than one page, and contains different FlowDocument objects), the second page starts in the footer of the first sheet. Also, I tried with A4 sheets, and It prints OK, so I'm wondering if there's a way to set the FlowDocument Page to that size.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the  PageSize of DocumentPaginator of your FlowDocument like below before printing:

```
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
                //Other settings
                DocumentPaginator paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)FlowDocument).DocumentPaginator;
                paginator.PageSize = new Size(816,1056) //Set the size of A4 here accordingly
                printDialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "My");

        }
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks